# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis from subquery

Tags: sql, oracle

Getting error in below SQL.

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action: Error at Line: 65 Column: 13
```

This SQL is generated by Hibernate.

```
select
        * 
    from
        ( select
            planrun0_.id as id1_38_,
            planrun0_.created_by as created_by2_38_,
            planrun0_.creation_date as creation_date3_38_,
            planrun0_.last_updated_by as last_updated_by4_38_,
            planrun0_.last_update_date as last_update_date5_38_,
            planrun0_.last_update_login as last_update_login6_38_,
            planrun0_.version as version7_38_,
            planrun0_.tenant_id as tenant_id8_38_,
            planrun0_.plan_id as plan_id10_38_,
            planrun0_.run_type as run_type9_38_,
            (
            SELECT
                status.id 
            from
                C_BIA_PLANRUN_STATUS status 
            WHERE
                status.plan_run_id = planrun0_.id 
            ORDER BY
                planrun0_.last_update_date desc LIMIT 1
                ) as formula3_ 
        from
            v2_planrun planrun0_ 
        where
            planrun0_.run_type=''
            and planrun0_.tenant_id='c2' 
        order by
            planrun0_.id asc ) 
        where
            rownum <= 10
```

Comment: Oracle does not support  `LIMIT`. With a current version you need to use `fetch first 1 rows only` instead

Answer (score 0):

Remove `LIMIT 1`

```
(
        SELECT
            status.id 
        from
            C_BIA_PLANRUN_STATUS status 
        WHERE
            status.plan_run_id = planrun0_.id 
        ORDER BY
            planrun0_.last_update_date desc       -- LIMIT 1
            ) as formula3_
```

Instead, you might use `ROW_NUMBER` such as

```
select ...
  from (select ...
          row_number() over (order by planrun0_.last_update_date desc) rn
        from ...
       )
  where rn = 1
```

Comment: after commenting  LIMIT 1 still same issue even i checked your ROW_NUMBER sql but still same issue.

Comment: @Nayak - it maybe isn't completely obvious, but in the `row_number()` version the `order by` moved into the `over()` clause - so did you remove the existing `order by` from the subquery?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `order by` in your subquery. It's erroring at that clause; it isn't getting to the (also invalid in Oracle) `LIMIT` keyword.

At first glance an equivalent would be:

```
        (
        SELECT
            MAX(status.id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY planrun0_.last_update_date)
        from
            C_BIA_PLANRUN_STATUS status 
        WHERE
            status.plan_run_id = planrun0_.id 
            ) as formula3_
```

... but it doesn't really make sense to have the analytic clause in the subquery order by a value from the outer clause, so I think you actually want a join instead, something like:

```
select
    * 
from
    ( select
        planrun0_.id as id1_38_,
        planrun0_.created_by as created_by2_38_,
        planrun0_.creation_date as creation_date3_38_,
        planrun0_.last_updated_by as last_updated_by4_38_,
        planrun0_.last_update_date as last_update_date5_38_,
        planrun0_.last_update_login as last_update_login6_38_,
        planrun0_.version as version7_38_,
        planrun0_.tenant_id as tenant_id8_38_,
        planrun0_.plan_id as plan_id10_38_,
        planrun0_.run_type as run_type9_38_,
        max(status.id) keep (dense_rank last order by planrun0_.last_update_date)
          over (partition by planrun0_.id) as formula3_ 
    from
        v2_planrun planrun0_ 
    join
        c_bia_planrun_status status 
    on
        status.plan_run_id = planrun0_.id 
    where
        planrun0_.run_type=''
        and planrun0_.tenant_id='c2' 
    order by
        planrun0_.id asc
    ) 
    where
        rownum <= 10
```

But this will never be true:

```
planrun0_.run_type=''
```

it needs to be

```
planrun0_.run_type is null
```

Comment: This working fine as native sql. But in hibernate @joinformula is adding alias name.SELECT
            MAX(status.id) planrun0_.keep (planrun0_.DENSE_RANK